# Angular-moment js shows older dates than what is actual

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I am working on a ionic application to retrieve posts in raddit.com using their API. Now my problem is when I tried to show the time of post using **angular-moment**, it shows the post is posted 47 years ago, where actually the post is posted some minutes ago. This is the line I used in the code. I am programming in a Ubuntu Machine.

```
<span am-time-ago="story.created_utc"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited the code into this

```
<span am-time-ago="story.created_utc | amFromUnix"></span>
```